# How to extract text from Word files using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I am trying to convert a large number (100,000) of word DOC files, these are quite old.  From around 1995 to 2000 version of Word, i supposed.  I keep going around in circles from what i see here in stack overflow and the MS documentation.

What i want do so is simply read the file, stick the text into a string, parse the string, take out the structure stuff (the file is actually a structured report, looks like Patient: Jon Doe).  At that point, I know what i am doing.  I can parse the string data, stick it into useful variables, then stick this data into a database.  But I do not know how to actually put the text into a string.  Any help?

PPS i found [this reference](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/316480-reading-text-from-ms-word-files-in-c) which supposedly puts a DOC file into a text file.  It's a start, but i'd rather avoid doing a bunch of file manipulations.

Comment: Have you looked into using ifilters?  I did some research a while back and it seems like they may be a good fit.  Here is a link - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IFilter.aspx

Comment: I found this which seems helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887133/easiest-way-to-process-text-from-ms-word-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to use the Word object model, you must always instantiate a certain version of Word on the client (since running Word on a server is not recommended). Unfortunately, you'll depend of the restriction of Word concerning older files, e.g. in Word 2010 you can open files from Office 95 only in sandbox mode (i.e you're not able to access the file content programmatically). Additionally, you'll have to deal with unknown template content (documents with macros attached, for example).

In your case I'd rather look for a 3p-component which allows to access the content. 
I know from document management systems like OpenText eDocs and Autonomy iManage that they use other tools to full-index documents of all types and can present the content in a viewer application. So if you look in this direction, may be you find something useful.

Answer (score -1):

A word file is just a normal file as far as your code goes.

Try this:

```
using System.IO;

StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath);
string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
streamReader.Close();
```

Comment: It sounds like he is looking to extract text from the document, not just read the file.