# How to convert a word document to a text file in c# without using microsoft.office.interop?

Tags: c#, file-conversion

I have plenty of different versions of word documents which have to be converted to text files.
 I hope this link brings you right way
[How to extract text from Word files using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287415/how-to-extract-text-from-word-files-using-c)
I want to read the content of the word document and remove all the formats(just have words in text files). I have done by using microsoft.office.interop(here, always instantiate a Word on the client) which is not recommended. So I am trying to create a c# project which should convert word to text automatically. Can anyone suggest me any 3rd party tool which should be efficient open source or reasonable price for all the versions of word to text file conversion in c#?

With Regards,
Shanthini

Comment: I look like to see that answered too.

Comment: word is just xml files under the skin.  change .doc to .zip and extract it and take a look, but you're going down a very deep rabbit hole here.

Comment: How many word files are you wanting to copy over? If a large amount then yes a third party is probably better, however if not you may want to look into filewriter and streamwriter, in which you copy the word document, create a new .txt file and paste the string into the txt file.

Comment: @deltree - you sure this works with `doc` (and not `docx`)?

Comment: @Corak I know it works with docx.  I haven't tried it on doc.

Comment: @Philip Gullick - I need to convert almost 100000 word files and all must be different versions. Yes, you are right. I am looking for the efficient 3rd party tool to use in my project. Thank you.

Comment: @Georgi-it. I saw the answer. But I haven't try the solution. Let me try again. Thank you very much indeed to all.

Comment: @user2285601 On the shear scale of things, and the fact your word files are in different versions, I wish you good luck!

Comment: @user2285601 let us know of yout progress

Comment: Sure. I will post here.

Comment: @deltree, this doesn't work for doc. It shows the error "File contains corrupted data" for doc documents :(

Comment: OpenXml works only for latest versions. I have seen some third party tools like spire.doc and aspose.words. Those are very expensive more than 500 $ for only one time process. But Those are more reliable and efficient. But before I go into it, any other suggestions please???

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found solution which perfectly works for me at the moment. I haven't test with 10000 documents. Here you go., http://sourceforge.net/projects/word-reader/?source=dlp
Comments and suggestions are expecting about this solution...

Thank you, 
Shanthini

Comment: It's a pity, that there is no source code attached, even it is hosted on sourceforge.

Comment: If you want to do this with a large number of file types (not just MSWord), see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41091943/495455

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want Interop, you can use [NPOI](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi). It's a matured open source project to work with Word and Excel files.

Please note that Word file can have a complex structure like nesting tables or joined/splitted cells. That's why, I think, NPOI doesn't have an explicit `SaveAsText()` method. But if you need only text from paragraphs or tables, you can easily extract it like this (.NET 6 example):

```cs
public static IEnumerable<string> WordFileToText(string wordFilePath)
{
    using var fileStream = File.OpenRead(wordFilePath);
    using var doc = new XWPFDocument(fileStream);
    var result = WordFileToText(doc);
    return result;
}

private static IEnumerable<string> WordFileToText(XWPFDocument doc)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    foreach (var bodyElement in doc.BodyElements)
    {
        if (bodyElement is XWPFParagraph paragraph)
        {
            result.Add(paragraph.Text);
            continue;
        }
        if (bodyElement is not XWPFTable table)
            continue;

        foreach (var row in table.Rows)
        {
            var tableLine = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var cell in row.GetTableCells())
            {
                foreach (var cellParagraph in cell.Paragraphs)
                {
                    tableLine.Append(cellParagraph.Text);
                    tableLine.Append("| ");
                }
            }
            result.Add(tableLine.ToString());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```