# Get the text from Email Attachments and write to a file

Tags: c#, vb.net, email-attachments, data-manipulation

I am working with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and I am trying to convert something from list form to string form.  I have found some solutions for similar problems but not this one in particular.

I would like to eventually have this code work:

```
Dim info As Byte() = New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(Utilities.GetEmailInfo(msg.Message).Attachments)
```

My end game is to take the text from Attachments and write it to a file.  If I use some of the other data types listed below such as ToData, the file turns out properly but I encounter an error with the code above because GetBytes cannot get the text from a list.  Is there another function I could use to get the text from the list?

The class that I need to convert contains the following:

```
Public Class EmailInfo
    Public FromData As String = vbNullString                            'FROM:
    Public ToData As String = vbNullString                              'TO:
    Public DateData As String = vbNullString                            'DATE:
    Public SubjectData As String = vbNullString                         'SUBJECT:
    Public MessageBody As EmailItem                                     'contents of message body
    Public AlternateViews As New Collections.Generic.List(Of EmailItem) 'list of alternate views
    Public Attachments As New Collections.Generic.List(Of EmailItem)    'list of attachments
End Class
```

The resource that I want to access is EmailInfo.Attachments.  This resource is stored as a list of type EmailItem.  The code for this type is as follows:

```
Public Class EmailItem
    Public ContentType As String = vbNullString         'CONTENT-TYPE data
    Public ContentTypeData As String = vbNullString     'filename or text encoding
    Public ContentTypeDataIsFilename As Boolean = False 'True if ContentTypeData specifies a filename
    Public ContentEncoding As String = vbNullString     'CONTENT-TRANSFER-ENCODING data
    Public ContentBody As String = vbNullString         'raw data of block
End Class
```

I have tried using some code such as String.Join but I end up with a blank string.

Please pardon my ignorance as I am new to VB.

Thank you all for all of your help!

Ryan

Comment: Not sure what you are up to, but `Attachments` is a collection so trying to write it out as a bunch of bytes wont provide a way to know where one item ends and another begins.  It will just be a blob.  *Maybe* you want to serialize it?

Comment: Ryan on each loop `File.AppendAllText` the email and attachment details so you know where one item ends and another begins. I would personally use a Database instead of a Text file, the text file will grow very,very large and once its over 5MB or so it will take ages to open.

Comment: Thank you @Plutonix,  serializing it worked perfectly.  I am well on my way to getting where I need to be.  If anyone is wondering I'm designing an email client that displays similarly to an IM client.

Answer (score 2):

This no trivial task. Attachments could be any number of *proprietary* formats: ".pdf", ".doc", ".xls", ".ppt", ".csv", ".vsd", ".zip", ".rar", ".txt", ".html", ".proj", etc, etc , etc.

Good news is all the work has already been done for you and I will show you how to generically read almost any file format and extract the text in this answer:

[Generically read any file format and convert it to .txt format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41091443/generically-read-any-file-format-and-convert-it-to-txt-format/41091943#41091943)

Make sure you read the **Info to set it up** paragraph.

So go ahead and reference TikaOnDotnet & TikaOnDotnet.TextExtractor to your project using NuGet (Tools menu > NuGet Package Manager).

I am assuming you have written code to extract the email attachments, using an Outlook Add-In [MSDN How to: Programmatically Save Attachments from Outlook E-Mail Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268754.aspx) or [just an app](https://www.matthewproctor.com/extracting-attachments-from-outlook-using-c-sharp) that uses Outlook via Interop, eg:

In C#:

```
private TextExtractor _textExtractor;
private string _attachmentTextFilepath = @"c:\temp\EmailAttachmentText.txt";
static void IterateMessages(Outlook.Folder folder)
{
    var fi = folder.Items;
    if (fi != null)
    {
        foreach (Object item in fi)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mi = (Outlook.MailItem)item;
            var attachments = mi.Attachments;
            if (attachments.Count != 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= mi.Attachments.Count; i++)
                {
                     //Save email attachments
                     mi.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile(@"C:\temp\" + mi.Attachments[i].FileName);

                     //Use TIKA to read the contents of the file
                     TextExtractionResult textExtractionResult = _textExtractor.Extract(@"C:\temp\" + mi.Attachments[i].FileName);

                    //Save attachment text to a txt file
                    File.AppendAllText(_attachmentTextFilepath, textExtractionResult.Text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In VB.Net:

```
Private _textExtractor As TextExtractor
Private _attachmentTextFilepath As String = "c:\temp\EmailAttachmentText.txt"
Private Shared Sub IterateMessages(folder As Outlook.Folder)
    Dim fi = folder.Items
    If fi IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each item As [Object] In fi
            Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem = DirectCast(item, Outlook.MailItem)
            Dim attachments = mi.Attachments
            If attachments.Count <> 0 Then
                For i As Integer = 1 To mi.Attachments.Count
                    'Save email attachments
                    mi.Attachments(i).SaveAsFile("C:\temp\" + mi.Attachments(i).FileName)

                    'Use TIKA to read the contents of the file
                    Dim textExtractionResult As TextExtractionResult = _textExtractor.Extract("C:\temp\" + mi.Attachments(i).FileName)

                    'Save attachment text to a txt file
                    File.AppendAllText(_attachmentTextFilepath, textExtractionResult.Text)
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```